# Running PHP files locally on Opera gives 404 error

Tags: mac, google-chrome, opera, localhost

I have been developing websites for quite some time now and recently web applications. I am trying to achieve strong cross-browser coherence with a new site that I am designing so I downloaded the Opera browser.

However, pointing Opera to localhost - which Chrome and Firefox have no troubles with - returns a 404 error. Is there some setting I am missing out? How do I test my site with Opera?

Note: It is a PHP site, not just HTML files; so I have to go through localhost for Apache to recognize and run the PHP files.

EDIT: The URL that raises 404 is a relative path to localhost (e.g. `http://localhost/~user/website/`

Here is a screenshot of Chrome and Opera 11.11, as seen below no files work on the Opera Browser.

[image: Chrome and Opera 11.11]

Comment: That last edit changes the entire attack of the question

Comment: Insufficient information on a lot of stuff, e.g. what's the OS, etc? I agree on "random"'s comment above, too. And that there were 3:rd party software installed (Is "Pow" a necessary, "out-of-the-box" component in all development sites?) should also be included in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had [Pow](http://pow.cx/) installed and it changed some file in `/etc/` on installation. Details, I do not know. But when I uninstalled this, Opera could view the files.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to access the `localhost` by its IP instead: `127.0.0.1` <sub>can't test though, just a guess</sub>

The issue with Opera is that it doesn't allow content to be displayed from `localhost`. You obviously need to [add `127.0.0.1` to the list of trusted websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836215/access-to-127-0-0-1-by-default-in-opera-10) and access it by IP instead.

[Another forum thread](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/server-management-97/localhost-access-fine-ie-not-opera-110117.html)  suggests to check for the "Anonymous access" option in IIS settings, if that's the web server being used.

Comment: going to localhost works fine. I can access localhost through the IP, "localhost" or the computer's domainname. The 404 arises then you try to access a relative path to localhost such as `http://localhost/~username/website`. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @Yasky interesting, I just tried on Opera using Mac's built in web server and was able to navigate to http://localhost/~username, though I do not have PHP enabled in my config so it just brings up the file. Try updating your question with which server and version of Opera you are using to test, whether it is the PC's built in, or your own Apache rollout

Comment: I am runnung Apache on my OS X and the versino of Opera is 11.11. I have also uploaded a picture http://t.co/74y4Ovq of Chrome and Opera visiting the same page. Apparently the problem exists for all files. What setup do you have for your Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your edit, have you included `index.php` in your Apache config’s `DirectoryIndex` statement?

PHP is not a client-side system, it’s a server-side program, so it doesn’t use URI-relative paths, it uses local file-system paths.

In other words, you can’t do things like

```
include "/common/blah.php"
include "http://localhost/common/blah.php"
etc.
```

You need to do something like the following instead

```
include "C:\web\project1\common\blah.php"
include "../../common/blah.php"
etc.
```

It’s strange that Chrome and Firefox would work; perhaps they have cached the page from some other source.